# Delete database value with bootstrap modal in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Delete database value with bootstrap modal in laravel

then what is route method for delete id please?

it is can not workin method!! is not working

Route:

`Route::post('/Adminpanel/delete','AdminController@destroy')->name('admin.destroy');`

Comment: you can use post as well as delete route method. Is your controller is resource controller?

Comment: please give more details. what you have tried and whats problem you facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `Delete Route` requires an argument to be deleted. the route should be like this.

```
Route::delete('/Adminpanel/{id}', 'AdminController@destroy')
    ->name('admin.destroy');
```

then you can call this route with the parameter to be deleted like this.

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.destroy', 1) }}"> 
    <!-- '1' here is the id of the resource need to delete. -->
    @csrf
    @method_field('DELETE')
</form>
```

and your controller function would be something like

```
public function destroy($id) {
    // your delete code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/Adminpanel/delete/{id}','AdminController@destroy')->name('admin.destroy');
```

in your view

```
{{ route('admin.destroy', $data->id) }}
```

and your controller function would be something like

```
public function destroy($id) {
 dd($id)
}
```